# Update iOS app with updated core data model

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm almost finished with my 1.1 release of my first iOS app, in it I have made two small changes to my core data model. More specific, I have added two attributes to one of my tables. This is my first core data app and therefore my first core data update to a live app, and I'm a bit nerveous about shipping code that might not work for my current users. Since it's a small update I'm guessing that Apples automatic migration method will do, but I don't want to guess.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],   NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],  NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
{

    //NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

In 1.1 I've added `NSDictionary *options`.

In my view controller I make sure the the needed rows isn't nil like this:

```
if (currentPage.inputType == @"drawing") {
    [pageView changeToDrawing];
} else if (currentPage.inputType == @"text") {
    [pageView changeToText];
} else {
    currentPage.inputType = @"text";
    [pageView changeToDrawing];
}
```

Basically, is these changes enough or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Here is a very helpful article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmUnderstandingVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH2-SW1) with regard to Core Data versioning that answers your question.

To sum it up in a few words, you will need to add a new model version to your project. This is necessary for the migration process.

**Edit**

Link above has changed and will redirect you to the following link: [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)

If all else fails, google: [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration apple developer](https://www.google.com/search?q=Core%20Data%20Model%20Versioning%20and%20Data%20Migration%20apple&oq=Core%20Data%20Model%20Versioning%20and%20Data%20Migration%20apple&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j60j0l2j62.2018&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=Core%20Data%20Model%20Versioning%20and%20Data%20Migration%20apple%20developer&oq=Core%20Data%20Model%20Versioning%20and%20Data%20Migration%20apple%20developer&gs_l=serp.3...7070.8284.0.8518.10.10.0.0.0.0.214.1516.0j9j1.10.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.HKbUcTXHfLs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=ff999713c9217bd7&bpcl=38897761&biw=1922&bih=1258).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have one related question. I added the attributes before I created the new model version, should I remove  the new attributes from my 1.0 version and only have them in my 2.0 data model version, or doesn't that matter? Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely you should remove them from 1.0 and add to next version. I've been bit by this recently actually.  1.0 should be *exactly* the same as what is currently deployed or else you will get an exception.  This includes both attributes as well as relationships.

Comment: Btw, a quick tip:  It's best that you test the migration process.  Install the version from app store, then run the latest (your project) on top of it.  That will be a true test to check that it's working.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I did that and it works. No crashes and the data was there. Had to make one small (view controller) change though, so thats a good tip. :)

Comment: Given link is no longer working. Could you update it please ?